# Convert Restangular Response to Model Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, restangular

We're building an AngularJS application and using Restangular for our REST-API.

Now my idea was to transform the response from the API to typed model JS objects. So we don't rely too much on the API if fieldnames differ from our code logic and we are independent in the frontend code to naming changes in the API. But is this the way to do it?

I'm lost when it comes to the point where we want to post back to the API. All of the functionality of the "restanguarlized" object is lost in the new typed model object. How can I transform it back to post against the API?

Is my approach wrong?

But what about solid code which doesn't break if the API has changed some properties? Or how can I see what properties my model offers without looking into the REST-API response. In my classic way of programming, I open up my Model-Class and can look up all properties offered by the model object!?

Thanks

here's some simplified example code of the implementation:

```js
function TypedModel(data) {
  this.foo = data.bar;
}

var typedModel;
Restangular.one('service', 'infos').get().then(function(data) {
  typedModel = new TypedModel(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach, no. Maybe you are used to a strongly typed language, like Java? It took me some time to adjust to Javascript, because it is so loosely typed.

I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but I have started setting up my classes as follows:

```
function TypedModel(pojo) {
    if (!TypedModel.validate(pojo)) {
        //Throw an exception if the POJO is not valid.
    }
    this.foo = pojo.foo;
    this.bar = pojo.bar;
    this.fooBar = pojo.fooBar;
}

TypedModel.validate = function(pojo) {
    return (pojo.foo && pojo.bar && pojo.fooBar);
};
```

This means that I can see exactly what properties my class should have, and if the API changes then I know I need to change my class.

But I am also in the process of moving over to Typescript, as it makes handling models a lot easier. I would definitely recommend looking into TS.

Comments welcome :)

Comment: To understand my problem you have to use Restangular. You get request entities from a REST API and get back specialiced objects. If you transform them to new objects the "special" behaviour (in form of functions etc.) is lost.

Comment: I do use Restangular, yes, but I don't know of a way to retain the Restangularized features once you save the object as a TypedModel. I just do a "post" when I need to save. But it would be nice, I agree.